Essential image of nearby cycles functor
Let $R$ be a Henselian discrete valuation ring. Let $S=\mathrm{Spec} R$ be the corresponding trait, with generic point $\eta$ and closed point $s$. Let $f:X\to S$ be a smooth proper morphism of schemes. Let $\ell$ be a prime invertible in $R$. Consider $\ell$-adic étale sheaves.  Let $R\Psi:D_c^b(X_{\eta})\to D_c^b(X_{\bar s})$ be the corresponding nearby cycles functor. We know that it restricts to a functor between categories of perverse sheaves $R\Psi:\mathrm{Perv}(X_{\eta})\to \mathrm{Perv}(X_{\bar s})$.
I wonder if it is possible to determine the essential image of the functors. For example, let $U\subset X$ be an open subset, $L$ be a lisse sheaf on $U$. Let $j_{\bar s}:U_{\bar s}\to X_{\bar s}$ be the inclusion.  Then the middle extension $j_{\bar s,!*}(L|_{U_{\bar s}}[\dim U_{\bar s}])$ belongs to $\mathrm{Perv}(X_{\bar s})$. Does it belong to the essential image of  $R\Psi:\mathrm{Perv}(X_{\eta})\to \mathrm{Perv}(X_{\bar s})$?
